# Segmentation Fault - Opening binary file

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

im a newbie on programming, and i need to show a binary file in my program in the first phase.

with the help of my teacher, i was able to do that, but when i was working late in the code i change somethings that i couldn't get back now :(

this is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    float cinzentos = 0, mlinha = 0, ppixeis = 0;
    unsigned char matriz[28][28][500];

    f = fopen("dados1.bin", "rb");

    if (f != NULL) {
        while (!feof(f)) {
            b++;

            if (b == 28) {
                printf(" soma: %f ", mlinha);
                printf(" cizentos: %f ", mlinha / 28);
                printf("\n");
                b = 0;
                a++;
                mlinha = 0;
                printf("%d %d %d", a, b, c);
            }

            if (a == 28) {
                a = 0;
                c++;
                ppixeis = (ppixeis / 28 * 28) * 0.1;
                printf("media de pixeis: %f\n", ppixeis);
                printf("\n---------------\n");
            }

            matriz[a][b][c] = fgetc(f);

            if (matriz[a][b][c] != 0) {
                printf("1");
                mlinha = mlinha + matriz[a][b][c];
                ppixeis++;
                fputc(matriz[a][b][c], p);
            } else {
                printf("0");
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

I think, that's is because the file opening, but im in looping trying to put this back together , need help

Comment: I would have to simply guess that's you're trying to access `matriz` with an index that is larger than the array. Before every access to it, check `a`, `b`, and `c` to see if they're good values.

Comment: Also, learn and start using a version control system (like Git). If you check in your code in frequently, then make a change that breaks your program, you can go back to a working version, and even perform a difference between the working version and the current broken version and see *exactly* what's different.

Comment: Also, while (!feof()) is always wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: It would be easier to use `for (a = 0; a < 28; a++) { for (b = 0; b < 28; b++) { for (c = 0; c < 500; c++) { int v; if ((v = getc(f)) == EOF) { ...break out of input loops on error, or exit... } matriz[a][b][c] = v; } } }`.

Comment: it was about the var c < 500 check, that was missing, someone post that but deleted the post, thanks to that guy!

also, thanks to the other persons who are giving guidelines to some lines that will give me problems in the future, i will take that too under observation of my code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is off by one

The

```
while (!feof(f)) {
            b++;
```

ensures that b will not start at 0 at the first read character